# AdminTask.createSIBus creates hidden bus in WebSphere

Tags: websphere, jython

I have noticed that when creating a Service Integration Bus in WebSphere using Jython, it does not appear immediately in the WebSphere console.

e.g. try this on WebSphere 7 - 8.5.5 :

```
./wsadmin.sh
```

> wsadmin>AdminTask.createSIBus('[-bus bus1 -description [A new bus] -busSecurity false ]')
>   wsadmin>AdminConfig.save()

Now Save changes to master repository and then view Buses under Service integration in the Web Console - it's not listed!

Now try creating a bus of the same name in the Web Console - it will fail (because it already 'exists') and when you save and apply changes - it appears. Anyone else experienced this and knows the root cause?

Cheers

Rod

Comment: are you sure that you are viewing Bus resources at the correct scope?  Also, have you refreshed the page after you executed the wsadmin command?

Comment: Buses are cell scoped so the most likely cause is you were logged into admin console when the script ran so it didn't update the console view of config until the change was attempted.

Comment: Thank you both for the rapid feedback and yes you were right - it was scope. I just tried it again by running wsadmin.sh from /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/bin and its working fine now - cheers!

Comment: Ok I have to own up here - I don't think it was even down to the scope. I think it was because I was not logging out of the WebSphere console while making changes via wsadmin, anyway its all working fine - thanks!